# Зарезервированноие слово from как переменная?

Tags: python

Подскажите как в Python можно извратиться и спользовать зарезервированноие from как переменную?

```
@dataclass
class URange:
    from: uint32
    to: uint32
```

Comment: по-моему никак... А зачем эти "извращения"?

Comment: у меня есть protobuf модель в которой есть эти 2 переменные

Comment: Назовите urange_from и urange_to, заодно будет понятней

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно - никак. Все языки имеют свои зарезервированные слова, без них существование языка невозможно. Обойти этот запрет никак нельзя. Это нецелесообразно, ибо будет путаница в коде. Так что, даже если это возможно, настоятельно не рекомендую это делать